# How can I override/hide the SetModified method on a DataRow?

Tags: c#, inotifypropertychanged, datarow

I'm trying to implement change notification on the `RowState` property of a `DataRow` object.

Here's what I have so far, but my `SetModified` method never gets called:

```
internal class DataRowEx : DataRow, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Events
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    #endregion

    #region Construction
    public DataRowEx(DataRowBuilder builder)
        : base(builder)
    { }
    #endregion

    #region Overrides
    protected new void SetModified()
    {
        base.SetModified();
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("RowState"));
    }
    #endregion
}
```

I suppose I could make it internal and call it myself from the object containing the row, but I feel like there should be a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DataTable` works with `DataRow` and, as such, will never call your `SetModified()` in `DataRowEx` (it "hides" the inherited member, it doesn't override it).

Probably the easiest way of achieving what you want is to also implement a custom `DataTable`,  override either `OnRowChanging()` or `OnRowChanged()`, and delegate to custom functionality in your `DataRowEx` from there.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing.